# Register generic types with concrete types in Unity by convention

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I'm wondering how to register my query handlers by convention with Unity, specifically, I got 3 interface types

```
IQuery
IQueryResult
IQueryHandler<IQuery, IQueryResult>
```

and concrete types look like

```
ArticlesQuery : IQuery
ArticlesQueryResult : IQueryResult
ArticlesQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<ArticlesQuery, ArticlesQueryResult>
```

As the number of registrations for the latter type is on the rise I'd like to register these by convention, but there seems to be no easy way of doing this.

A single mapping looks like so

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryHandler<ArticlesQuery, ArticlesQueryResult>,
        ArticlesQueryHandler>();
```

For registration by convention I tried something along the lines of

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()
       .Where(t => typeof (IQueryHandler<,>).IsAssignableFrom(t)), WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces);
```

but that failed miserably (no types were found nor registered). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses
    .FromLoadedAssemblies()
    .Where(t => 
        t.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
            i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces);
```

By the way, `IQueryHandler<,>` is not assignable from any type because it is an open generic type.